Why is the current used in calculating the dissipating power 25A?
In this video, the guy calculated the dissipating power for a mosfet by using I = 25A. Why is it 25A? I can't even find 25 in its datasheet.

What shud you think determines a circuit's maximum current"==?

If you go to around the 10:30 mark in the video, you will see that the microtype blog post he was using as reference stated the design should be able to handle 25A stall current. He is just using this number to determine the power dissipation in the FET.

He mentioned "in a stall", suggesting that he is referring to motor current at start-up.
I suppose, then, that 25A is his estimate of stall/start-up current for some motor, and isn't some value he found in the MOSFET's datasheet.
